# Calculate the difference between two nodes

Tags: orbeon

Is it possible to find the difference two nodes and use the that difference as a constraint for a particular control.

```
<xforms:bind id="DebitRebate1"
    nodeset="instance('charge-options-setup')/Pattern_Setup1/Pattern1/DebitRebate1"
    type="xforms:double" 
    constraint=". &lt; instance('charge-options-setup')/Pattern_Setup1/Pattern1/DebitPrice1
                and instance('charge-options-setup')/Pattern_Setup1/Pattern1/DebitPrice1-. &gt;
                instance('charge-options-setup')/Locations_Patterns/Debit_Minimum_Margin"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the difference between two nodes as a constraint on another node, and the code you quote seems about right. Just a couple of comments:

- In your XPath, instead of `&lt;` and `&gt;` you can use just `lt` and `gt`. This performs a [value comparison](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-value-comparisons), and makes the expression easier to read.
- Also make sure you have spaces around node named: instead of `DebitPrice1-.` use `DebitPrice1 - .`. This is necessary, as `-` can be used as part of an element or attribute name, so `foo-bar` point to `<foo-bar>` not what's in `<foo>` minus what's in `<bar>`.